# I want to show to rows from the database in Crystal view C# window form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, crystal-reports

```
private void AllMemberReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ReportDocument crypt = new ReportDocument();

     string AppPath = Application.StartupPath;
     string ReportPath = @"AllMemberReport.rpt";
     string ReportFullPath = Path.Combine(AppPath, ReportPath);

     MessageBox.Show(ReportFullPath);

     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\GymDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
     connection.Open();

     SqlDataAdapter dadptr = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Member", connection); // Specifying SQL statement and Database connection  

     DataSet dset = new DataSet(); // creating instance of DataSet  
     dadptr.Fill(dset); // Filling DataSet  

     crypt.Load(ReportFullPath);
     crypt.SetDataSource(dset);

     crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crypt;

     connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What specific error messages did your code encounter?

Comment: its just showing column name not rows

Comment: First check whether there is data in your Member table and DataSet, and change your ReportFullPath to an absolute path for testing. Finally, call crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();